# Error Uninstalling Enthought Canopy 1.5.4

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to uninstall Enthought Canopy 1.5.4 (64-bit) so I can download the updated Canopy 1.5.5. However, when I try to uninstall through Control Panel's Programs and Features, an error appears saying:

"The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable. Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'canopy-1.5.4-win-64.msi' in the box below".

Does anyone know how to fix this, or where to download the old Canopy 1.5.4 installer/MSI? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft's MsiZap utility, described in (and attached for download to) this article: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy